# Want to fetch data from different model using Id of different table?

Tags: yii

> I have a model for two tables message and User which contain fields:
>
> Message: id message created_date status
>
> User: id usr_name
>
> I have another table message_to without a model:
>
> message_to: id message_id user_id status
>
> Now, My problem is I need to fetch username from usertable through
>   user_id in message_to in the current message model. How can I create
>   relation for this? I don't want to use query builder here.

Answer (score 1):

In Message model:

```
<?php

class Message extends CActiveRecord {
    // ...
    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'user' => array(
                self::BELONGS_TO,
                'User',
                '{{message_to}}(message_id, user_id)'
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Then call like `$message->user->usr_name;`

To have an ability to get user's messages you can write a relation in User model:

```
<?php

class User extends CActiveRecord {
    /...
    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'messages' => array(
                self::HAS_MANY,
                'Message',
                '{{message_to}}(user_id, message_id)'
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Then call like `foreach($user->messages as $message) { ...`

Comment: Thank You, Evgeniy. Can I use the relation 'user' in the 'message' model?

Comment: Yes, it's a relations function for Message model. I've just updated the answer with the example of usage.

Comment: Property "Message.message_to(message_id)" is not defined. I am getting this exception when I created the relation in the message model, I think it shows message doesn't have the field  message_to(message_id), some help please.

Comment: I've edited the code in my answer: `{{message_to}}(...`. Try in this way.